# Multiple Series of Line in Kendo-UI

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I would like to draw two dataset (stats and stats2).

I could able to draw one series (stats),

```
dataSource: {  data: stats},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1sgt4810

but when I add the second one, it does not draw.

```
dataSource: {  data: stats, stats2 },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1sgt4810/2/

I know there is an option of doing it as follows

```
                      series: [{
                            type: "line",
                            field: "y",
                            categoryField: "x",
                            name: "Path1",
                            style: "smooth",
                            data: stats,
                            markers: {
                             visible: false
                          }
                        }, {
                            type: "line",
                            field: "y",
                            categoryField: "x",
                            name: "Path2",
                            style: "smooth",
                            data: stats2,
                            markers: {
                             visible: false
                          }
                        }],
```

Because in the future, I will have many of the lines, I need to know how to handle with multiple lines in a modular way.

Comment: `{  data: stats, stats2 },`; that's not valid json.

Comment: My point, is that it isn't valid; that's why it didn't work.  You likely would have gotten a parse error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Rather than using `dataSource`, you can supply multiples `series` and give them each a `data` attribute. You can see this in the example on [Kendo UI's site](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/index).

```
series: [{
    name: "Path1",
    //other properties
    data: stats
}, {
    name: "Path2",
    //other properties
    data: stats2
}],
```

Here's [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sgt4810/3/) with both lines shown. I don't believe there's a way to do it without having multiple series.

**Option 2**

If you want to merge the lines into one, you could concatenate the arrays like so:

```
dataSource: [].concat(stats, stats2)
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sgt4810/9/) for that.

**Option 3**

Another possibility is to generate the series based on how many arrays you have. For example:

```
series: [ stats, stats2 ].map(function (data, idx) {
    return {
        type: "line",
        field: "y",
        categoryField: "x",
        name: "Path" + (idx + 1),
        style: "smooth",
        data: data,
        markers: {
            visible: false
        }
    };
})
```

You can see that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1sgt4810/20/).

Comment: thanks for the effort, however I do not neither want to concatenate them or use separate datasource since I need to handle multiple linesources. In addition to that, this data source attributes are exactly same.

Comment: @ilyasUyanik, I guess I'm not sure what you're after. You want the data from both `stats` and `stats2`, but you don't want them to be on the same line nor two have two separate lines. What do you want it to look like?

Comment: @ilyasUyanik I've added another example, if you're just trying to avoid manually entering a series for each datasource

Comment: Any idea for the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173359/mouse-hover-or-click-event-in-line-chart

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your jfiddle you problem is that you trying to pass two  stats array in to datasource and would want it to draw a line for you instead you need to modife your exitent stat

```
 { x: 1227.35612555829, y: 6016.67309037634,  z: 6013.67309037634},
```

take a look at 
http://jsfiddle.net/1sgt4810/19/

Comment: Could u elaborate a little bit. why did you add z property? You need to take a look the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1sgt4810/2/

Comment: I know how to add two lines manually by adding another series as mentioned in the question. However, I would like to avoid manual work. What if I will have 50 series of line? I need to find a way to make it modular.

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/1/ the following. It could be done using scatterLine.

Comment: I would be glad if you have an idea of the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687368/reverse-y-axis-in-scatterline-kendo-ui